# I want to set the blured image of the image as background

Tags: android

I want to set the blurred image of the image as background.My image view area is like rectangle.In case of square images,the backround image doesn't keep its aspect ratio.
How can I set the squared image as background in rectangular region.

I have used the below code

```
Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),true);
  final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(MyApplication.getContext());
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);
    //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    renderScript.destroy();
```

screen shot is given below.I want to fill the background  with blurred image
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via Glide using blur transformation. Try below code

```
  public static void setBlurImageToBackground(final Context context, final String path, final ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Glide.with(context).load(path)
                    .apply(bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(25)))
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }, DELAY_DURATION);
}
```

**NOTE: Add below dependencies**

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
 compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1'
```

Comment: It cause an error "you must not call settag() on a view glide is targeting " @Abdul Waheed

Comment: it is not the error of glide you must be setting tag in you image view you please check that

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQEuo.png      this is the output.I want to fill the background. @Abdul Waheed

Comment: bitmapTransform in red,

Do we need to import something?